# Delphi "Undeclared identifier" in constant array

Tags: constants, delphi-xe4, delphi

I have the following statements:

```
type tx = Record
      a : string;
      b : integer;
     end;

const
     x : tx = (a: 'a'; b: 1);
     xs : array of tx = ((x));
```

The compiler gives me: "Undeclared Identifier 'x' "

I don't get why, since 'x' is declared just before the 'xs' array declaration and constant type matches. I appreciate any enlightment;

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187952/delphi-declaring-constant-record-type-containing-constant-arrays

Comment: I attempted to fix your code. But it still doesn't match the error that you report. Please don't post fake code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in your original answer was not the code that led to the error message that you reported. I've attempted to fix it as best I can, but it really does pay to post the actual code rather than an approximation to it.

Anyway, assume this is what you have.

```
const
  x: tx = (a: 'a'; b: 1);
  xs: array of tx = ((x));
```

The declaration of `x` is fine. That defines what is known as a [typed constant](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Typed_Constants).

The declaration of `xs` is invalid for two reasons:

1. You cannot declare typed constants for dynamic array types.
2. The values in a constant declaration must be [constant expressions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Constant_Expressions). This rules out using `x` as a value in any constant declaration.

Now, what you probably have, judging from the error is more like this:

```
const
  x: tx = (a: 'a'; b: 1);
  xs : array [0..0] of tx = ((x));
```

And that gives the error that you report. Namely:

> E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'x'

That's because of item 2 in my list above. The code fails to compile because `x` is not a constant expression.

Quoting from the documentation for constant expressions:

> A constant expression is an expression that the compiler can evaluate without executing the program in which it occurs. Constant expressions include numerals; character strings; true constants; values of enumerated types; the special constants True, False, and nil; and expressions built exclusively from these elements with operators, typecasts, and set constructors.

Note that *typed constants* do not appear in the list, which is why your `x` is not a constant expression.

Given all this, the best you can do, to declare a constant, is probably:

```
const
  xs: array [0..0] of tx = ((a: 'a'; b: 1));
```

Comment: The declaration of x is not ine. It should be `b: 1`, not `b = 1`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Thanks. It turns out that the question was riddled with errors. And I naively reproduced them.

Comment: @David: Tsk, tsk, tsk. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const
  x1 : tx = (a: 'a'; b : 1);
  x2 : tx = (a: 'aa'; b : 11);
  xs : array[1..2] of tx = ( (a: 'a'; b : 1) , (a: 'aa'; b : 11) );
```

Some online references:

- [Understanding and Using Record Data Types in Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/beginners/a/record_type.htm)
- [How to Declare a Constant Record in Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2007/qt/const_record.htm)
- [How to Declare and Initialize Constant Arrays in Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2006/qt/const_array.htm)

EDIT: David's answer contains the key - the constant definition cannot use expressions which are not constant themselves.

Comment: @Adrian The values in a constant declaration must be [constant expressions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Constant_Expressions) and `x1` and `x2` are not constant expressions.

Comment: David. You are right. I've missed the `[0..0]` on the example. The `constant expression` thing is the answer for the compiler error. My goal was to declare globally the `x : tx = (a: 'a'; b: 1);` statment and use it in many `array [n..m] of tx`. You have any suggestion on how I can accomplish something alike?

Comment: @user2383818 Please read my answer. I think I cover all the angles there.

Comment: David. Your answers says why I can't use that sequence of statments. So far so good. What I'm asking now, is how I can use the globally declared `const` statement `x : tx = (a: 'a'; b: 1);` in other units of the app, without the need of redeclaring that statement. Perhaps with `StringList`? I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: @user2383818 I think I answered the question that you asked. If you have comments on my answer, please make them as comments to my answer rather than Adrian's. If you wish to comment, use the <at> symbol to that the recipient is notified. If you want to ask a new question, please do so.

Answer (score -1):

I decided to declare a variable statement wich will hold the global constants as a dynamic array. At run time, I populate that array with the propper constants statements that are needed for that particular unit.

```
interface
...
type tx = Record
  a : string;
  b : integer;
end;
...
const x1 : tx = (a: 'a1'; b: 1);
      x2 : tx = (a: 'a2'; b: 2);
      x3 : tx = (a: 'a3'; b: 3);
...
var xs : array of tx; 
...
implementation
...
procedure SetXs;
begin
  SetLength (xs, 1);
  xs [0] := x1;
  SetLength (xs, 2);
  xs [1] := x3;
end;
...
```

I don't know if this is the best or most elegant way, but it suits me for now. I'm accepting suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that you asked. This is you giving an update of how you are currently thinking about your specific problem. The site here is all about question and answer. If you want to post an answer, you must address the question that was asked. Also, that's a pretty poor way to initialize a dynamic array. Declare it as `TArray<tx>` and initialize it with `xs := TArray<tx>.Create(x1, x3);`

Comment: David. It solves my actual goal, that was (if you have read my comments) to use a globally declared constant in a local declared array. I appologize if I wasn't clear enough when I posted the question. I thank every one that have contribbuted someway to lead me to the above solution. Regards.

Comment: David. The use of `Generics` to initialize an array is very handy, but I couldn't find an `Add` method, so I infere from this  (correct me if I'm wrong) that in that case, I must use the traditional way: `SetLength` to enlarge the array and then assign the new value to the recently added item of the array. Is that so?

Comment: You are now asking a different question. Can't we finish this one first?

Comment: David. Ok Consider it finished.

Comment: Well, I guess you might accept what you deem might be the best answer.